# SQL query to calculate sum of row with previous row

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my table

```
date     count of subscription per date
----      ----------------------------
21-03-2016      10
22-03-2016      30
23-03-2016      40
```

Please need your help, I need to get the result like below table, summation second row with first row, same thing for another rows:

```
date     count of subscription per date
----      ----------------------------
21-03-2016      10
22-03-2016      40
23-03-2016      80
```

Comment: Do you have id column in this table?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.date, (
    SELECT SUM(numsubs) 
    FROM mytable t2 
    WHERE t2.date <= t.date
) AS cnt
FROM mytable t
```

Comment: but i have only one table .

Comment: Main query and subquery are working with one table `mytable`

Comment: thank u dear , now it working correctly , thank u very much again .

Answer (score 3):

You can do a cumulative sum using the ANSI standard analytic `SUM()` function:

```
select date, sum(numsubs) over (order by date) as cume_numsubs
from t;
```

Comment: Is there a reason for an anonymous downvote on a correct answer?

Comment: I dont know, but plus is mine. `OVER` is something new for me, thanks!

Comment: @mnv . . . This is much, much, much more efficient than the correlated subquery approach.  I strongly suggest that you learn about analytic functions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My current DBMS is MySQL. There are no `OVER` support unfortuneally.

Comment: @mnv . . . The question is tagged Oracle, which fully supports such functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select sum(col1) over(order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) cnt from mytable;
```